# Apache Camel - ftp component - need to use absolute path

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration

I am trying to upgrade a product that uses an older camel version (2.15.1).
I am trying to upgrade the camel version to 2.17.5

In the code base, camel ftp component is used with absolute paths. After upgrade we saw that, files could not be consumed due to the following error:

***SftpComponent doesn't support absolute paths, "xxx" will be converted to "yyy". After Camel 2.16, absolute paths will be invalid.***

I can see that absolute paths are not supported starting with 2.16:

http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html

For our case, it will be very costly to change the existing code base.

My question : Is there any possibility **to force**  camel ftp 2.17.5 to support absolute paths as before in 2.15.1 (via config or other setting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's not possibble. Commit: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/ca6d74205815269b7b3caf32ca57cb73c1a7299a

Comment: Hi,

As I understand absolute urls will not be supported in the feature.

The strange thing is that org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations  (implementation of the org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileOperations interface ) uses absolute urls for operation!!!

Is not absolute path the cleanest solution?